# What happen's to content inside in rows on columns defined as varchar, when illegally reduced length?

Tags: mysql, size, varchar, reduce

Certainly a noobish question, but I got to ask: :-) Assuming a column of type varchar and length 255 and the longest string stored in a row at this column shold have length 200. What happens, if I altered the columns length to less then 200? Would the strings all get "cut"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, it will allow you to alter the column, it will truncate strings longer than the new length, and it will generate a warning.

```
mysql> create table t (v varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into t values ('12345678901234567890');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table t modify column v varchar(10);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'v' at row 1 | 
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+------------+
| v          |
+------------+
| 1234567890 | 
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you have the [SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html) `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` set, the warning becomes an error and the ALTER will fail.

```
mysql> alter table t modify column v varchar(10);
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'v' at row 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation, @Bill. All questions in my head are solved. :-)

Comment: Worked for me: Query OK, 2919470 rows affected, 27062 warnings (45 min 41.31 sec)